# Function pulling from API keeps running

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created this function.

I think I'm missing something very obvious but when I call this function, it keeps running where instead I only want "tweeter" to run once when it is called. Instead, it seems to be looping every minute or so and then posting again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function tweeter() {
    //Fetch API Documentation
    fetch('[MY API URL]').then(response=> response.json()).then(function (data) {
        //Function to create array
        //Define Array
        var array =[];
        let tweetText ='';
        //Loop data.data
        for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) { 
            var minutes = (data.data[i][1]);
            //Push values to Array
            array.push(minutes);
            }
            //SUM of array
            var sum = array.reduce(function(a, b){
                return a + b;
            }, 0);
            //Return rounded value of average of Cork City sensors.
           let sensorAverage = (Math.round(sum / data.data.length));
           /* Messaging based on the SensorAverage returned.

           Based on EU PM2.5 AQI
           
           0-10:
           10-20:
           20-25:
           50-75:
           75-800:
           800:

           */
           if(sensorAverage <= 10){
             tweetText = " \n\n0-10 = Good. \n\nThe air quality is good in Cork City at the moment. \nEnjoy your usual outdoor activities worry-free. " ;
            } else if((sensorAverage >=10.1) && (sensorAverage <=19.9)){
                tweetText = "\n\n10-20 = Fair. \n\nThe air quality is fair in Cork City at the moment.. \nEnjoy your usual outdoor activities.";
            } else if((sensorAverage >=20) && (sensorAverage <=24.9)){
                tweetText = "\n\n20-25 = Moderate. \n\nThe air quality is moderate in Cork City at the moment. \nEnjoy your usual outdoor activities. Sensitive groups should consider reducing intense outdoor activities, if you experience symptoms.";
            } else if((sensorAverage >=25) && (sensorAverage <=49.9)){
                tweetText = "\n\n20-25 = Moderate. \n\nThe air quality is moderate in Cork City at the moment. \nEnjoy your usual outdoor activities. Sensitive groups should consider reducing intense outdoor activities, if you experience symptoms.";
            }else if((sensorAverage >=50) && (sensorAverage <=74.9)){
                tweetText = "\n\n50-75 = Very Poor. \n\nThe air quality is very poor in Cork City at the moment. \nConsider reducing intense activities outdoors. Sensitive groups should reduce physical activities.";
            } else if((sensorAverage >=75) && (sensorAverage <=)){
                tweetText = "\n\n75-800 = Extremely Poor. \n\nThe air quality is very poor in Cork City at the moment. \nReduce physical activities outdoors. Sensitive groups should avoid physical activities outdoors.";
            } else if (sensorAverage > 800){
                tweetText = "\n\n>800 =  Catastrophicly Poor. \n\nThe air quality is catastrophic in Cork City at the moment. \nAvoid outdoor activities.";
            }
    
    var tweet = "The average reading across Cork City is currently " + sensorAverage + "*. " + tweetText + "\n\n*Based on EU PM2.5 AQI. \n\n#CorkAirQuality";
    T.post('statuses/update', { status: tweet }, tweeter);
  
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking it's this line :-

`T.post('statuses/update', { status: tweet }, tweeter);`

This can be possible if you're passing `tweeter` as a callback function to your `T.post` code (I am not aware of how you implemented it).

So everytime the **POST** request completes, the `tweeter` callback might be getting triggered.

Comment: Whoops, I  should have added more context. 

T.post is using twit package https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit

Comment: Yup it's the callback thing. Your tweeter function gets called back after each post request.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! 
Now to dive in and fix that. Appreciate the help